# Utility for counting total files inside of multiple Zips?

Tags: zip, winrar, file-archiver

On Windows 7, I have 120 Zip files, each Zip containing images.

Is there any utility or software with which I can confirm how many total images are combined in all 120 Zips?

Comment: Do you talk about `jpg` only or also about `tiff`, `psd`, `png`, `gif`, etc?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Only .jpg files

Answer (score 0):

You can try command like this:

```
rar -t *.zip |find /i ".jpg" /c
```

`-t` to test archives (and list files)
`find` to get all files which contain `.jpg` in filename and `/c` to count them

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell script will count `.jpg` files in all Zip archives in the folder
and its sub-folders:

```
$ZipRoot = 'C:\Path\To\Folder'
$Count = 0

$ZipFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $ZipRoot -Recurse -Filter '*.zip'

$Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

$Results = foreach( $ZipFile in $ZipFiles ){
    $Count += $Shell.NameSpace($ZipFile.FullName).Items() |
        Where-Object { $_.Name -match '\.jpg$' } |
        Measure-Object |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
    }

Write-Host "Count= ", $Count
```

Comment: I should've been more specific, I mean subfolders within the .zips, it only counts the root level of the zip

Comment: @j.i.h.: That would take a recursive function, like [this](https://damashiuchi.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/get-child-items-in-a-zip-file-recursively-using-windows-powershell/).

Answer (score 0):

To count the total number of `.jpg` files inside multiple zips in the current folder with some Linux shell (which [can](https://superuser.com/q/608106/116475) be accessed on Windows):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.zip' -exec unzip -l {} \; | grep -c '\.jpg$'
```

E.g., if the folder contains:

```
a.zip
123.zip
test.zip
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Utility for counting total files inside of multiple Zips

One can use [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) (gratis). Select all the archive files in Windows Explorer, right click -> 7-Zip -> Test  Archive:

[image]

[image]